# How to configure wget for a proxy (RHEL 8)?

Tags: linux, rhel, wget, proxy

I have a machine with installed above RHEL8.
I have to download a package using the **wget** command (as root) but it tells me:

> "Connecting to ip:8080... failed: Connection time out."

The command I used is that:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://ip:8080/package.rpm
```

I tried to edit the **wgetrc** file by inserting the proxy:

```
https_proxy = http://ip:8080/
http_proxy = http://ip:8080/
ftp_proxy = http://ip:8080/
```

and I added my credentials for authentication:

```
proxy_user=myuser
proxy_password=mypassword
```

Saved the file, sent back the command but still unable to download the file.
Where am I wrong? :(

Comment: Do you still get the same error after inserting the proxy/adding creds? If you don't mind, please update your question with that info. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Grace! Yes, I get the same error after inserting the proxy/adding creds. I noticed that entering the ping command "google.com" fails to connect. Is port 8080 closed? How can I see if it is closed?

Comment: Hi there, if you do nmap <ip address> can you see if port 8080 is open?

Comment: I did "nmap ip_address and it tells me: 
Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes".

I reach this ipaddress through another machine and I also downloaded the famous package while in this machine (rhel8) it fails.
Do you think the port is closed?

Comment: Hi Grace! In the end, I removed the proxy lines and could download the package.